# what is the standard way to maintain a stable user session?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

What is the standard way to maintain a stable user session in ASP.NET without worrying about IIS recycles, disconnected users, re-opening browsers and so on. **I would like for our users to not have to login except once per month, whatever happens**!

Also does it matter if I am using my own login control (not the standard asp.net login control)? If I understand correctly, I think I would need to create an authentication ticket manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set an authentication cookie on the user's machine and set it to expire at the end of the month.  Then your authentication code can simply check for the presence of a cookie and automatically log in the user based on the cookie's contents.

Comment: problem is, forms authentication will always forward the users to the login page before I can do anything about it.

Comment: @a b: Why can't the login page check for the cookie on `Page_Load` and re-forward accordingly?

Comment: @a B: forms authentication does not force the user to the login page if there is a cookie already present (and valid). @David's answer is correct... just extend the auth cookie expiration date.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a 'standard' way. It will depend upon your application. The basic change is that you put the session data into some form that persists across recycles. I have an application where I was saving information about a 'trip' and I serialized this out to an xml file. Here is the code that I used in that case. It may be a useful staring place:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using Cravens.Infrastructure.Logging;

namespace TruckTrackerWeb.Code
{
    public class TripSessions
    {
        private const string _relativeSesionFile = "~/App_Data/TripSessions.txt";
        private readonly string _sessionFile;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        private readonly Dictionary<Guid, TripSession> _sessions;
        private readonly TimeSpan _maxAge = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0);

        public TripSessions(ILogger logger, HttpContextBase httpContextBase)
        {
            _logger = logger;


            _sessionFile = httpContextBase.Server.MapPath(_relativeSesionFile);

            _sessions = ReadSessionFile();
        }

        public TripSession CreateSession(string userName, int truckId)
        {
            try
            {
                TripSession tripSession = new TripSession
                                              {
                                                  Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                                                  Expiration = DateTime.Now + _maxAge,
                                                  TruckId = truckId,
                                                  UserName = userName
                                              };
                _sessions[tripSession.Id] = tripSession;
                SaveSessionFile();
                _logger.Debug("Created session for: username=" + userName + ",truckid=" + truckId);
                return tripSession;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.Error("Failed to create session. ", ex);
            }
            return null;
        }

        public TripSession GetSession(Guid id)
        {
            if(_sessions.ContainsKey(id))
            {
                return _sessions[id];
            }
            return null;
        }

        private void SaveSessionFile()
        {
            _logger.Debug("Saving trip session data to file.");
            List<string> lines = new List<string>();
            foreach (KeyValuePair<Guid, TripSession> keyValuePair in _sessions)
            {
                TripSession tripSession = keyValuePair.Value;
                lines.Add(tripSession.ToString());
            }
            File.WriteAllLines(_sessionFile, lines.ToArray());
        }

        private Dictionary<Guid, TripSession> ReadSessionFile()
        {
            _logger.Debug("******READING TRIP SESSION FILE**********");
            Dictionary<Guid, TripSession> result = new Dictionary<Guid, TripSession>();

            if(!File.Exists(_sessionFile))
            {
                _logger.Debug("The session file does not exist. file=" + _sessionFile);
                return result;
            }

            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(_sessionFile);
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                TripSession tripSession = TripSession.ParseLine(line);
                if(tripSession!=null && (DateTime.Now - tripSession.Expiration)<_maxAge)
                {
                    result[tripSession.Id] = tripSession;
                    _logger.Debug("ADDED---->" + line);
                }
                else
                {
                    _logger.Debug("EXPIRED-->" + line);
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Won't using sql server for saving sessions achieve the same result?

Comment: No doubt. This is just an example of saving the session to xml. In my case, my IOC created an instance of this class in singleton scope. So that was one disk read per app domain. Not much disk banging going on here. So most of the time, this behaved just like the in-memory session manager. The only thing that was this does is the session will persist across iis recycles. I agree, could have gone to a db. But seemed overkill for my case.

Answer (score 1):

Take your session `out of process` and increase the `SessionTimeout` to max.